# Adding element in the middle of xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML Below:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Change xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Area>
            <Sender>
                <LogicalId>tyhu</LogicalId>
            </Sender>
            <CreationDateTime>2021-04-29T14:33:13Z</CreationDateTime>
            <Id1>
                <Id>163067354</Id>
            </Id1>
        </Area>
        <Data>
            <Prob>
                <DateTime>2021-04-29T14:33:13Z</DateTime>
            </Prob>
        </Data>
    </Change>
```

I need to add two elements Id2 and Id3 after Id1.

Desired Output:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Change xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Area>
            <Sender>
                <LogicalId>tyhu</LogicalId>
            </Sender>
            <CreationDateTime>2022-04-29T14:33:13Z</CreationDateTime>
            <Id1>
                <Id>6654</Id>
            </Id1>
            <Id2>C1</Id2>
            <Id3>29</Id3>
        </Area>
        <Data>
            <Prob>
                <DateTime>2022-04-29T14:33:13Z</DateTime>
            </Prob>
        </Data>
    </Change>
```

I tried below xslt but no luck:-

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
        <xsl:template match="Id1">
            <Id2>C1</Id2>
            <Id3>29</Id3>
            <xsl:next-match/>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please let me know if it is possible to do through xslt. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"` yet uses an instruction that requires XSLT 3.0. Which XSLT processor will you be using? Also "no luck" is not a good description of a problem.

Comment: Hi @michael,
Sorry, getting below error:-
"Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation"

Comment: I asked which processor you are using. If you don't know, see here how to find out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="Id1">
  <xsl:next-match />
  <Id2>C1</Id2>
  <Id3>29</Id3>
</xsl:template>
```

To complete the task with XSLT-1.0, you would have to use the *identity template* and replace the `<xsl:next-match />` by `<xsl:copy-of select="." />`, but with XSLT-3.0, you can use the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, as you did in your example.

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Change xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Area>
      <Sender>
         <LogicalId>tyhu</LogicalId>
      </Sender>
      <CreationDateTime>2021-04-29T14:33:13Z</CreationDateTime>
      <Id1>
         <Id>163067354</Id>
      </Id1>
      <Id2>C1</Id2>
      <Id3>29</Id3>
   </Area>
   <Data>
      <Prob>
         <DateTime>2021-04-29T14:33:13Z</DateTime>
      </Prob>
   </Data>
</Change>
```

Comment: With XSLT 3.0, you *can* use `xsl:mode ...`, not *"have to"*. And with a processor that supports XSLT 3.0, all that OP needs to do is move the `<xsl:next-match/>` instruction ahead of the two literal result elements.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks. That really improved the whole template.

Comment: Hi @zx485
I am getting spaces at the starting.

Comment: Not sure at which place you get spaces. One possibility to remove spaces from elements is adding `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` at the stylesheet level.